# How to make Chart JS ignore the scale between DatasSets

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to create a multi-bar chart where one of the bars is really lower than the other ones. (I'm comparing low numbers X high numbers X high numbers)

This is my dataSet:

```
[
    {
        "label": "# Negócios Fechados",
        "data": [ 8, 5, 3, 12 ],
        "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)"
    },
    {
        "label": "# Valor Total",
        "data": [ 16000, 25000,4500, 36000 ],
        "backgroundColor": "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)"
    },
    {
        "label": "# Ticket Médio",
        "data": [ 2000, 5000, 1500, 3000 ],
        "backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)"
    }
]
```

This is what my chart looks like:
[image: chart]

The "# Negócios Fechados" one is there, but It's so low that It's impossible to mouse hover it.

I want to know if it is possible to make this single bar ignore the scale of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a multi-axis chart, similar to this [sample](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/scatter-multi-axis.html).

Please take a look at the following runnable code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    datasets: [{
        label: "# Negócios Fechados",
        data: [8, 5, 3, 12],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
        yAxisID: 'y2',
      },
      {
        label: "# Valor Total",
        data: [16000, 25000, 4500, 36000],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)"
      },
      {
        label: "# Ticket Médio",
        data: [2000, 5000, 1500, 3000],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)"
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        position: 'right',
        beginAtZero: true
      },
      y2: {
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: It didn't work man... But thanks for the effort